# Can a closed (non-trivial) subspace of an incomplete vector space be complete?

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces

While thinking about the statement:

> A subspace of a **complete** vector space is closed if and only if it's complete.

I was trying to drop the first "complete" and see what gets broken.

And my question is:

Can a closed (proper) subspace of an incomplete vector space be complete?

If the answer is yes, I'd be happy to see some relatively simple example (over $\mathbb R$), since I haven't had functional analysis yet.

If the answer is no, please give an example of an incomplete but closed subspace of an incomplete vector space over $\mathbb R$. For this case, I was thinking about $C^1(\mathbb R)$ and $f_n=|x|^{1+\frac{1}{n}}$ yet I couldn't think of any closed (proper) subspace with $f_n$.

Thanks a million!

Comment: Does $\{0\}$ work?

Comment: Of course, the vector space $\{0\} \subseteq V$ is always a complete vector space whatever norm you put on $V$.

Comment: Good timing, user73445

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva, user73445, thank you for the responses. And what about a non-trivial subspace? (I'll edit the question.)

Comment: @mathusiast : A finite-dimensional subspace will always be closed and complete too, whatever space you're working in. That is because you can produce a bijective isometry with $\mathbb R^n$ in that case (isometries preserve Cauchy sequences).

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva, and infinite-dimensional?

Comment: @mathusiast Take a direct product of a complete space (any dimension) with an incomplete space (infinite dimensional, of course).

Comment: @egreg: thank you! Do you have an example of an incomplete but closed subspace of an incomplete vector space over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @mathusiast Wouldn't the direct product above furnish one?

Comment: @egreg: I thought you were commenting on the question in the title. Could this work: direct product of $\mathbb R^2$ and $(C^1(\mathbb R), ||·||_\infty)$. Then the resulting vector space is incomplete. And a subspace (say, direct product of the $y$-axis and the whole $C^1$) is **closed** yet incomplete. Right? Thank you for looking into it!

Comment: @mathusiast I'd say this is correct. Just notice that the canonical embedding of a factor in the direct product induces the relative topology.

Comment: @egreg : For an incomplete vector space $V$ over $\mathbb R$, $V$ is an incomplete but closed subspace of itself. I get that you're just trying to get examples of things but... try to find some yourself! You can't just ask for a thousand examples and think that you're going to "feel" what's going on afterwards. If you really want to "feel" what's going on, you need to try to find these examples yourself!

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Your example is of course fine, but a *proper* incomplete subspace is perhaps better.

Comment: If you think about your question with the strong topology (the one induced by the norm), your question leads up to this : suppose you have an incomplete normed vector space, i.e. a vector space with "holes" (non-convergent Cauchy sequences). Can you find subspaces with holes and other subspaces with no holes? Well of course, choose the right subspaces that go around those holes. The dimension is irrelevant. There are plenty of examples out there.

Comment: @egreg : If you are okay with finite *codimension*, you can always take $n$ linearly independent vectors in an incomplete vector space, say $v_1, \dots, v_n$, and look at $V = W \oplus \langle v_1,\dots,v_n \rangle$. Then $W$ is an incomplete closed vector subspace of $V$.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I'm *not* looking for examples. I already gave one as generic as desired.

Comment: @egreg : oh god I'm really sorry, I thought you were OP for a second! I lost track of the comments. Really, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can. Just take an incomplete space $V$ and a complete one $W$; then $V$ can be identified with a closed subspace of $V\oplus W$ with the product topology (that is normed if $V$ and $W$ are); this subspace of $V\oplus W$ is not complete, but closed, because it is $\{(v,w):w=0\}$.

Another example: take a noncomplete normed space (for instance the continuous functions on $[0,1]$ under the $L^1$-norm). [Any finite dimensional subspace is complete.](http://planetmath.org/everyfinitedimensionalnormedvectorspaceisabanachspace)

Comment: But your example has some kind of relying on the product topological structure. If a incomplete space $V$ can not decomposed as direct product of two subspaces, then is there still proper complete subspaces of $V$?

Comment: @SamWong Take your favorite incomplete normed space and a one-dimensional subspace thereof.

Comment: It does make sense. Thanks egreg.

Comment: Hi egreg. After the day you replied me, I suddenly realized another thing that a normed vector space might not induce a inner product(it can induce a inner product if and only if it satisfies the parallelogram law). If there is no inner product on our space, then we cannot form the orthogonal complement space of the one-dimensional subspace, and hence we cannot decompose our space into the direct sum of two subspaces. How do we modify your example if we encounter this case(i.e. there is no inner product)?

Comment: @SamWong I didn't use inner products anywhere.

Comment: But if we want to decompose our general space $V$ into the direct sum of a one-dimensional subspace and its orthogonal complement, then we need inner product right? Hmmm...is there other way to decompose space into direct sum of subspaces...?

Comment: @SamWong For the orthogonal complement you need an inner product; but not all normed spaces have one inducing the norm. What would it be needed for, anyway?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I misunderstand your example. Sorry egreg.